# Hiding a div when link is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I am trying to create a div with some text. Then there is a link below and when clicked the div should hide.
This should be only be java script, i.e. no Jquery

See my try at below.. Is it possible to do it somehow inside the a element? Do I have to create a function inside a JD script?

```
<div id="text">
    Lorem Ipsum blablal b blablaba balbla bla.
</div>
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('text').hidden">Click me to hide the div</a>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use the following:

[**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/J5ehZ/)

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('text').style.display = 'none'">...</a>
```

---

Alternatively, if you want to use unobtrusive JavaScript, this would work if you add an `id` to the link.

[**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/9EN3L/)

```
document.getElementById('link').addEventListener('click',function(){
    document.getElementById('text').style.display = 'none';
});
```

---

The above examples *hide* the link with `display:none`. If you would rather *remove* the element:

[**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/tYghL/)

```
document.getElementById('link').addEventListener('click',function(){
    document.getElementById('text').remove();
});
```

---

If you want to toggle the visibility and hide/show the element, you could use [`.classList.toggle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList).

[**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/EM93p/)

```
document.getElementById('link').addEventListener('click',function(e){
    document.getElementById('text').classList.toggle('hidden');
});
```

CSS

```
.hidden {
    display:none;
}
```

Just take [the support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList#Browser_compatibility) this method has into consideration.

Answer (score 2):

Using this code will let you hide/show the div whitout having to add any `<script>` tag or JavaScript library.

```
<div id="text" style="display: block">
    Lorem Ipsum blablal b blablaba balbla bla.
</div>
    <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('text').style.display === 'block' ? document.getElementById('text').style.display = 'none' : document.getElementById('text').style.display = 'block'">Click me to hide the div</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

josh is right, just add a third argument to the addEventListener as false to capture the event in bubbling phase

```
document.getElementById('link').addEventListener('click',function(){
    document.getElementById('text').style.display = 'none';
}, false);
```